# I am unable to migrate data into the Sitecore/Content Field items through GatherContent module

Tags: sitecore

I am unable to fill data into the Sitecore/Content Field items through GatherContent module in Sitecore for content gathering mapping to Sitecore items.

**I am unable to migrate the Home data items from Gathercontent to the sitecore/Content/Home data items.**

**I mean to field to field level data mapping or sharing.**

Kindly prefer the below images.

[image]

> I want to migrtate GC(Gathercontent)home item title and text data into
>   Sitecore fields Home items title and text.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi .. I got the solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solutions.

> In content migration from Gather content to sitecore items , doesn't
>   directly map with the already created Sitecore items,it create new
>   items to the Sitecore with new GC Content Id:,GCPath
>   [shared]:,MappingId: and Last syn date.

**kindly prefer the below image**

[image]

just update this all same data with the already created sitecore items field.

suppose want to add in the home item field ..
[image]

Now click the Update from Sitecore ribbon gathercontent update button to update the content and select the appropriate project and template.

[image]

next
[image]

Now confirm the locations items and click update , this update already created all Sitecore items.
[image]

comment below if you find best solutions, for this.